# Using Implied properties in directory name

Tags: wix, wix3.5

This is an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
<Product Id="*" Name="SetupProject1" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="MySoftware" UpgradeCode="d2192e52-f4f6-461c-9d8e-eb66067df09a">
    <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />

    <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
    <MediaTemplate />

    <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="SetupProject1" Level="1">
        <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponents" />
    </Feature>
</Product>

<Fragment>
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
        <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
            <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="[Manufacturer] SetupProject1" />
        </Directory>
    </Directory>
</Fragment>

<Fragment>
    <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
        <!-- TODO: Remove the comments around this Component element and the ComponentRef below in order to add resources to this installer. -->
        <!-- <Component Id="ProductComponent"> -->
            <!-- TODO: Insert files, registry keys, and other resources here. -->
        <!-- </Component> -->
  <Component Id="CMP_NEW">
    <File Id="FILE_NEW" Source="New Text Document.txt" KeyPath="yes" />
  </Component>
    </ComponentGroup>
</Fragment>
```

The folder that created in ProgramFiles is `[Manufacturer] SetupProject1` and not `MySoftware SetupProject1`. Do I do it right? If not, how can I do it please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a variable $(var.Manufacturer) and use it like so:

Define like this: `<?define Manufacturer = "MySoftware"?>`

```
<Product Id="*" Name="SetupProject1" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="$(var.Manufacturer)" UpgradeCode="d2192e52-f4f6-461c-9d8e-eb66067df09a">

<Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="$(var.Manufacturer) SetupProject1" />
```

That will work..:)

Answer (score 0):

The problem I have is that you can't set the preprocessor variable to a value defined during the installation, say in the UI. I'm trying to set the directory name to a property that is given by the User.

So far the key way I've seen to get around this is to use a custom action to change the Directory datatable to the value of the property you would otherwise reference. Just make sure you time the custom action so that it doesn't happen before the directory is normally set, otherwise it might be overwritten.

I'm still looking for something a little prettier however.